# How do you make a submit button redirect to another page after the user has inputted the correct password?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, redirect

could you please help me find out what's wrong? After login, it is supposed to redirect you to another page, but nothing happens. The user name is: Joshua and the password is: Joshua#123.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login: MessengerX</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Tania\Documents\Website\style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="HTML website called MessengerX. Send messages to anyone who has logged in.">
  <meta name="author" content="Joshua Hurley">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, MessengerX, Joshua Hurley, Website, Supremefilms">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
    // Below function Executes on click of login button.
    function validate() {
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      if (username == "Joshua" && password == "Joshua#123") {
        alert("Login successfully");
        location.replace("www.youtube.com"); // Redirecting to other page.
      } else {
        attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have " + attempt + " attempt left;");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt == 0) {
          document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="C:\Users\Tania\Documents\Website\Screenshots\face.jpg" height="500" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <h1 style="color:"><b><i>Login: MessengerX</i></b></h1>
      <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
        <label>User Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        <button type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" />
      </form>
      <b><i>Submit</i></b>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to move the script to the bottom of <body>, after the declaration of all other HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`window.location.replace("https://www.youtube.com")`

Answer (score 0):

You can move code inside `window.addEventListener('load'` or you can move script after `dom` at the end

**Suggestion:** use the entire URL with HTTP or HTTPS.

`location.replace("https://www.youtube.com");`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.

      /// code here
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As leonardofmed mentioned, better place your script just befor `</body>` closing tag,
because you need to load html first, so script can see elements, otherwise at it's start there is no elements yet, so this will cause error, as for redirecting you can use:

```
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `<form><button type="button" ...` instead

`<form><button type="submit" ...` has its own logic ("magic"), which is doing the problem.

2. use protocol in url location.replace("https://www.youtube.com"), otherwise it's relative path

BTW never validate password on client!!!